# Как соединить C и C#

Tags: c#, c, конвертация

Как можно (и возможно ли вообще) соединить код написан на C (игра) с библиотекой написанной на C#? Переписать игру на C# я не могу так ка это не реально. Может быть можно создать DLL с библиотеки на C# и использовать ее в C? Уже искал и по поводу конвертации с C# на C но это тоже не возможно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Прямая конвертация невозможна, слишком уж разные языки.

Для соединения с библиотекой на C# есть традиционно два пути:

1. Использование COM-объектов. .NET-классы можно экспортировать как COM-объекты, тогда к ним можно получить доступ из чистого C.
2. Прослойка на C++/CLI. Напишите мини-библиотеку на C++/CLI, которая будет иметь интерфейс, доступный из чистого C (то есть, функции в интерфейсе определены как `extern "C"`), и внутри себя вызывать .NET-овский код.

Я бы порекомендовал второй вариант.